# How can I make a CALayer clickable?

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-animation, calayer, catransformlayer

I am using CATransformLayer to create a bunch of layers and animate them with 3D perspective to make a cube (something like this)

[image: CATransformLayer with sublayers]

**What's the best way of adding a UIButton to one of the sides to this cube?** I would like to be able receive events and access the buttom from an IBOutlet.

I've tried creating a UIView with a button inside it into my XIB and inserting its layer into the CATransformLayer, it shows up but the button isn't clickable. I have a feeling this is because UIKit deals with the Touch/events side of things, the layers are just there to do the drawing.

(btw, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110543/how-can-i-make-a-ui-element-added-via-addsublayer-respond-to-touch-events?rq=1), but feel this case is different enough to warrant a new post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root view thats hosting all the layers is getting all touches for the layer tree

in there you gotta do

```
CALayer *touchedLayer = [self.rootLayer hitTest:touches.anyObject.locationInWindow];
```

from the comment: if you want to check during animations assk your presentation layer:

```
CALayer *touchedLayer = [self.rootLayer.presentationLayer hitTest:touches.anyObject.locationInWindow];
```

Comment: But if you have active animations, you have to send the hitTest message to your view's root layer's presentation Layer. In your example, if the view's layer is rootLayer, you'd send the hitTest message to self.rootLayer.presentationLayer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daij for the hint, here's my solution - would appreciated any comments/improvements

```
- (IBAction)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    CALayer *layer = [sender.view.layer hitTest:location];

    BOOL contains = [self.btnPlay.layer.sublayers containsObject:layer];
    if(contains)
    {
        [self.btnPlay sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }


}
```